# Get the source directory of a Haskell Stack & Turtle script from within the script itself

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, haskell-turtle

I've created a [stack interpreted script](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#script-interpreter) using [Turtle](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle) and I want to be able to get the directory where the script is (regardless of where it's been called from).

This can be done in Bash by parsing `$0` or `$BASH_SOURCE[0]` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/get-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within-the-script-itself), however, I can't work out how to do it with Stack/Turtle?

I've tried the [FindBin](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/FindBin) library but it didn't work (it just returned the current working directory).

My script is currently defined like so:

```hs
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack --resolver lts-13.3 script
    --package turtle
    --package text
-}
```

Is this possible with a stack script?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the `executable-path` package to get this information:

https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2019-07-07/executable-path-0.0.3.1/System-Environment-Executable.html

Comment: The `getScriptPath` function from that package worked perfectly; the docs say it's experimental but it did exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you for your reply!